# How can DRAM memory speeds be improved?

Tags: computer-architecture

What are some ways with which we can improve the speed of dynamic RAMs?

Comment: In the past, data has been transferred by row. Build 3D memory cubes accessed by (sub)plane.

Comment: This is a question about electronics, so doesn’t belong here. You can try [electronics.se].

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I disagree. Considering faster electronics is off-topic here. But considering variations in the logic of hardware architecture, whatever it might be, that would increase the performance of RAM would be perfectly acceptable. Nothing says we are restricted to software, and hardware architecture is explicitly on topic. This is fortunate since the distinction between hardware and software is not always obvious.